# since i switched to python 3, my flask page stopped displaying ASCII characters correctly

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ascii

things such as this started to appear:

```
(nÃ£o Ã© necessÃ¡rio
```

up until then, i had a line in the .py file with

```
# import sys
# reload(sys)
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

and this used to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was remove the

```py
# !/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: latin-1
```

from the beginning of the file.